# Proof that there are only two directions of rotation around an axis?

Tags: rotations

It seems self-evident that there are only two directions an object can rotate in around a linear axis (clockwise and counter-clockwise).  But as math has taught me over the years, *self-evident* is not the same as *correct*.  Can it be proven that there are only two directions of rotation around an axis?

Comment: Yes, it can. Please first define "direction of rotation around an axis". That will be the biggest challenge.

Comment: Not sure how to prove this either, but here are some thoughts that might help this along: I suppose we would need to start with some agreed upon definitions. For rotation, perhaps a "transformation preserving size, orientation and position"? Now what about direction? Arguably, all rotations are counterclockwise rotations by some angle which would indicate only $1$ direction. What do you mean when you say there are two directions?

Comment: Maybe the thing to prove is that all rotations about a given axis can be uniquely characterized by some angle from $-180˚$ to $180˚$.  Of course, this requires a workable definition of angle.

Comment: This is more interesting from a dynamic perspective, where an object is rotating and the trick is to show that this motion looks, at a sufficiently small timescale, like (counterclockwise) rotation about some axis.

Comment: Alternatively, you may wish to prove that every transformation with certain properties is indeed a rotation about some axis.

Comment: Perhaps we can state this as follows: For any line $\ell$ in ${\bf R}^3$, the space of nontrivial homomorphisms ${\bf R}\to{\rm Stab}_{{\rm Aff}({\bf R}^3)}(\ell)$ has two connected components.